# Shared Java data objects between client and server but also have side-specific methods

Tags: java, serialization, polymorphism, client-server

I'm making a client-server game where sockets are used to pass serialized data objects from a shared package.  My idea was that clients would send different command objects to the server while the server would send update objects to the client.  Then, each object that inherits from command or update would have an executeCommand() or applyUpdate() method so the server or client could run it when it's received.

When I started actually coding this I quickly realized this wouldn't work the way I wanted it to because the execute or update method would need some sort of reference to the client or server specific objects even if it's compiled on the other side.

My new solution is to instead implement a getCommandName() method that just returns a string that's different for each command type but so far it's been very annoying and hard to read.  Is there a more standard way of doing something like this that would let me keep some of the polymorphic behavior I intended?

Also, sorry in advance if somehow this question was already answered.  There were a few questions similar to mine but they didn't seem to quite answer what I was really trying to find out.

Comment: Have you considered using the RMI Api of Java? This sounds pretty much like that would save you some time.

Comment: Your basic idea is OK but you need to provide some kind of context parameter to `executeCommand()` or whatever you're going to call this method.

Comment: First solution : sending the full context like in RESTful.
Second : the server (and the client) already owns the complete context and you have to provide only IDs of objects in the parameters of the send/call.

Comment: If I understand that correctly, you want to change Server/Client internal state by sending commands. So I agree with EJP that your approach is not too bad. You'd just need to give the command some entry point to alter the state. So it should look like `executeCommand(State context)`. You also may have look into [command pattern](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2077569/core-java/java-tip-68--learn-how-to-implement-the-command-pattern-in-java.html).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  I'll look into the command pattern.  It might be what I need but I'm not sure yet how much it would help me just yet.